# Use native Phonegape js in GWT using JSNI

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, phonegap-plugins, jsni

I wanna run this phonegap native alert on GWT using JSNI

```
navigator.notification.alert(
        'You are the winner!',  // message
         null,         // callback
        'Game Over',
        'Done'
  );
```

I've tried this:

```
public static native void testNativeAlert()/*-{

   navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
     null,         // callback
    'Game Over',
    'Done');}-*/;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#writing, don't forget about `$wnd` to access global properties!

> ```
> public static native void alert(String msg) /*-{
>   $wnd.alert(msg);
> }-*/;
> ```
>
> Note that the code did not reference the JavaScript window object directly inside the method. When accessing the browser’s window and document objects from JSNI, you must reference them as $wnd and $doc, respectively. Your compiled script runs in a nested frame, and $wnd and $doc are automatically initialized to correctly refer to the host page’s window and document.

So in your case, you have to use `$wnd` to access `navigator`:

```
public static native void testNativeAlert()/*-{

   $wnd.navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    null,         // callback
    'Game Over',
    'Done');
}-*/;
```

---

Side note: the docs aren't clear, but are you sure that phonegap lets `callback` be null? Otherwise look into that JSNI docs I linked above further.